# python sqlite3 backup memory db to disk hangs

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, debian-buster

This script hangs on `con.backup`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES (NULL)")
bkp = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
con.backup(bkp)
bkp.close()
con.close()
```

But if I comment the `INSERT` it works perfectly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)")
# cur.execute("INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES (NULL)")
bkp = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
con.backup(bkp)
bkp.close()
con.close()
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What if you commit first before the backup?

Comment: It works perfectly by adding `con.commit()`.
The libsqlite3 library is autocommit by default and I thought the python module too.
So I checked in the documentation and it doesn't :-(.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Where did you add con.commit()?

Comment: @MrT77 After the 2 `cur.execute` to commit them and before `con.backup(bkp)`.